# Can OkHttp used in Java Projects without android

Tags: java, okhttp

We see many good reviews about rest client OKHTTP , but we are in dilemma that can we use it in normal java projects (ie: Spring batch, java batches) as we see it is primarily used in android applications

Could some one throw some light on this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Absolutely yes! Include the dependency and start using it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp works great on non-Android Java projects. It’s used extensively in Square’s backends, where it carries tens of thousands of calls per second between services.

It works well on its own, and also when paired with cloud mesh tech like Envoy and Istio.